# Order custom wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have a WordPress custom loop which looks like this:

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'meta_key' => 'publication_type',
    'meta_value' => 'uma',
);
```

This shows 6 posts with publication_type equal to `"uma"`. The `publication_type` is a field created with Advanced Custom Fields.

I've also created the field `publication_year` which contains `2019, 2018, 2017`,...

How is it possible to order all my posts descending?

The following example doesn't do a thing:

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'order_by' => 'publication_year',
    'order' => 'DESC'
    'meta_key' => 'publication_type',
    'meta_value' => 'uma',
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $args = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,    
    'meta_query' => array(                                                   
                        array(
                            'key'     => 'publication_type',
                            'value'   => 'uma',
                        ),
                    ),
    'meta_key' => 'publication_year',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
 ));
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn’t work. This gives more Posts then there are under publication_type=“uma”

Comment: @DennisPerremans I edited my above code. please check now.make sure your  meta_key name is correct.

Comment: No sorry, it still shows posts with publication_type="member" and publication_type="press".

Comment: @DennisPerremans  R u sure you stored custom field with name 'publication_type' because there is nothing wrong with this code it is working fine for me. I test it.Please reverify your field name and check its value in database. because here it is not taking 'publication_type' value that's why the problem occurs.

Comment: Yes, I can assure you that the correct field name is "publication_type" which is a select. And "publication_year" is a numeric field. I've double checked it by printing the values for these custom fields.

Comment: I've found the issue ! :-) I did `new WP_Query` twice.
It works like a charm. Thanks for your help.